# AWS Sagemaker online feature store data storage

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, feature-store

Where does AWS Sagemaker online featurestore store the features. Does it use DynamoDB?

Answer (score 0):

SageMaker Feature store has an online and offline store.
The online store is a low latency cache and the offline store is S3.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/feature-store-getting-started.html#feature-store-concepts

Comment: can i ingest data into only the online store as a cache

Comment: Yes you can configure your Feature Group to be online only: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/feature-store.html#how-feature-store-works